# Does VS optimize casting to the same type?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, optimization

```
int a = (int)5;
```

Does VS optimize that (remove the cast)? The situation above is trivial but I'm writing some template classes which take arbitrary type arguments in constructor:

```
template <typename U>
MyClass(U argument)
{
    T a = (T)argument;
}
```

In most cases the cast is needed to avoid compiler warnings but when T = U then the cast is redundant. Or maybe is there a better way to implement that?

Comment: Write that, compile it and take a look at the IL (using ILDASM or a decompiler like Reflector).

Comment: If at all you need a cast, use a c++ cast not a c-style cast. In c++ when you use `(T)x` the compiler actually tries to use a predefined sets of C++ cast and it might actually end up using a `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: If you're really worried, you can still include `<type_traits>` and write something like `T a = std::is_same<T,U>::value ? arg : (U) arg;` -- though honestly that would be a bit silly.

Comment: @Damon The only thing I might be "worried" about is overhead of casting. Wouldn't your solution add just a different (but still an) overhead?

Comment: Thee is no cast in the compiled output; there couldn't be. Think about it: in C++, the cast that will be used must be determined at compiled time and the compiler must have the types of both the operand and the result. The compiler uses those types to choose the exact action it needs to output. Once the compiler decides that you are asking for a static cast from `int` to `int`, there is nothing left for the compiler to do. There is no such thing as a code fragment that converts an `int` to an `int`.

Comment: @EuroMicelli: This is correct _most of the time_ (for `int` in any case!) but not necessarily for all types. It does not matter that the types are known at compiletime. A cast from `T` to `U` may still have to change the integer representation of the address, which is not a no-op.

Comment: @NPS: Overhead should be zero. `std::is_same<T,U>::value` is of `enum` type, so the ternary expression is necessarily constant -- it can only ever evaluate one way, based on the types known at compile time. But it's in my opinion still silly to "optimize" for such a thng, because if a cast (or pointer modification, or whatever) is necessary, _then it is necessary_. And if it is not necessary, a compiler that is not totally broken will not emit code for it anyway.

Comment: @Damon You're right, didn't think it was compile-time. But compilers **might** be broken, there's always that risk. :P

Comment: @Damon: certainly. I never said it was true for all type combinations. My comment was specific about `int`->`int`, but it applies to all cases where `T` = `U`; that was the question: "will the compiler optimize if `T` = `U`?". In fact, it's true for `T`->`T` regardless of what `T` is. `T`!=`U` is an entirely different matter. In particular, C++ templates are not "generics": every combination of template parameters will generate a new implementation, so if `T` = `U` = `some_specific_type`, the compiler has no choice but to output nothing for the cast, because there is nothing to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following Oded's hint from comments, I did a test in gcc-4.7.2 and MVSC-2012:

```
template <typename U, typename T>
void assign1(const T& t, U &u)
{
    u = (U) t; // CAST
}

template <typename U, typename T>
void assign2(const T& t, U &u)
{
    u = t;    // WITHOUT CAST
}

int main()
{
    {
        int t = 12;
        int u = 1;
        assign1(t, u);
    }
    {
        int t = 12;
        int u = 1;
        assign2(t, u);
    }
}
```

`assign1` assembly code (gcc):

```
!{
!    u = (U) t;
assign1<int, int>(int const&, int&)+3: mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
assign1<int, int>(int const&, int&)+6: mov    (%eax),%edx
assign1<int, int>(int const&, int&)+8: mov    0xc(%ebp),%eax
assign1<int, int>(int const&, int&)+11: mov    %edx,(%eax)
!}
```

`assign2` assembly code(gcc):

```
!{
!    u = t;
assign2<int, int>(int const&, int&)+3: mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
assign2<int, int>(int const&, int&)+6: mov    (%eax),%edx
assign2<int, int>(int const&, int&)+8: mov    0xc(%ebp),%eax
assign2<int, int>(int const&, int&)+11: mov    %edx,(%eax)
!}
```

They are same in gcc.

`assign1` assembly code(MSVC):

```
001413EE  mov         eax,dword ptr [u]  
001413F1  mov         ecx,dword ptr [t]  
001413F4  mov         edx,dword ptr [ecx]  
001413F6  mov         dword ptr [eax],edx
```

`assign2` assembly code(MSVC):

```
0014142E  mov         eax,dword ptr [u]  
00141431  mov         ecx,dword ptr [t]  
00141434  mov         edx,dword ptr [ecx]  
00141436  mov         dword ptr [eax],edx
```

They are same in MSVC, too.

So, both compilers omit the cast.